# não é uma expressão GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Olá . Estou tentando executar uma determinada Query no Oracle e que está me resultado o seguinte erro : 
  "não é uma expressão GROUP BY" . 
Abaixo está a relação das tabelas e query:

CONTA

```
NRO_CONTA|COD_AGENCIA|NOME      |SALDO  |LIMITE|ENDERECO|DDD_FONE|
---------|-----------|----------|-------|------|--------|--------|
    30001|         30|ANA TERESA|   1000|   500|        |        |
    30002|         30|CAROLINA  |   5500|  2500|        |        |
    30003|         30|JOAQUIM   |    800|     0|        |        |
```

FUNDO DE APLICAÇÃO

```
NRO_CONTA|DATA_APLIC         |COD_FUNDO|NRO_COTAS |VLR_APLIC|
    ---------|-------------------|---------|----------|---------|
        30007|2010-01-04 00:00:00|        1|999.430325|     1000|
        45004|2010-01-04 00:00:00|        1|749.572744|      750|
        30002|2010-01-04 00:00:00|        2|999.350422|     1000|
```

FUNDO DE COTAS

```
COD_FUNDO|DATA_COTA          |VALOR_COTA|
---------|-------------------|----------|
        1|2010-01-01 00:00:00|         1|
        2|2010-01-01 00:00:00|         1|
        3|2010-01-01 00:00:00|         1|
```

QUERY

```
SELECT C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO ,
       ROUND(SUM(FA.COTAS * FA.VALOR_COTA),2) AS SALDO_APLIC
FROM CONTA C
  JOIN (
    SELECT FA.NRO_CONTA , FA.COD_FUNDO, FA.NRO_COTAS AS COTAS , DC.VALOR_COTA AS VALOR_COTA
    FROM FUNDOS_APLIC FA
    JOIN (SELECT COD_FUNDO, MAX(DATA_COTA) AS DATA_COTA , VALOR_COTA FROM FUNDOS_COTA GROUP BY COD_FUNDO) DC ON FA.COD_FUNDO = DC.COD_FUNDO 
    GROUP BY FA.COD_FUNDO, FA.NRO_CONTA 
  )FA  ON C.NRO_CONTA = FA.NRO_CONTA
```

Basicamente o que desejo fazer é o seguinte :  Criar uma view que retorne os dados de TODAS as contas correntes e inclua o valor aplicado em fundos de investimento. Colunas da view:
 - número da conta
 - nome do correntista
 - saldo em conta corrente
 - Saldo total em fundos de investimento (fundos_aplic.nro_cotas * fundos_cota.valor_cota)

Alguém saberia me ajudar na resolução deste problema ?

Comment: Em seu SELECT mais externo você utilizou a função de agregação SUM, contudo você não tem uma cláusula GROUP BY para este SELECT mais externo, tem uma cláusula GROUP BY mas apenas para o SELECT mais interno em uma das partes do JOIN. Tente GROUP BY C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO.

Comment: Olá amigo. Agradeço pela ajuda. Mas continuo com o mesmo erro : (

Comment: Talvez você não tenha postado o comando SELECT completo pois a parentização está incorreta e, além disso, você apelida tanto a tabela FUNDOS_APLIC quanto o seu SELECT de FA.

Comment: Está completo. Qual seria o problema com a parentização ?

Comment: Não está claro a que você deseja aplicar esta cláusula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Há tempos não trabalho com Oracle, mas tentando ajudar, pode ser a falta de uma função de agregação (SUM, MAX, MIN, etc.) em alguns campos que não estão apontados como campos de agrupamento (GROUP BY).

Abaixo, destaquei no código alguns destes campos:

```
SELECT C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO ,
       ROUND(SUM(FA.COTAS * FA.VALOR_COTA),2) AS SALDO_APLIC
FROM CONTA C
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
        FA.NRO_CONTA, 
        FA.COD_FUNDO, 
        FA.NRO_COTAS AS COTAS ,  // SEM FUNÇÃO DE AGREGAÇÃO
        DC.VALOR_COTA AS VALOR_COTA // SEM FUNÇÃO DE AGREGAÇÃO
    FROM 
        FUNDOS_APLIC FA

        JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    COD_FUNDO, 
                    MAX(DATA_COTA) AS DATA_COTA , 
                    VALOR_COTA   // SEM FUNÇÃO DE AGREGAÇÃO
                FROM 
                    FUNDOS_COTA 
                GROUP BY 
                COD_FUNDO) DC ON FA.COD_FUNDO = DC.COD_FUNDO 
    GROUP BY FA.COD_FUNDO, FA.NRO_CONTA 
  )FA  ON C.NRO_CONTA = FA.NRO_CONTA
```

Para ter uma ideia melhor do problema, destaquei o código abaixo:

```
            SELECT 
                COD_FUNDO, 
                MAX(DATA_COTA) AS DATA_COTA , 
                VALOR_COTA   // SEM FUNÇÃO DE AGREGAÇÃO
            FROM 
                FUNDOS_COTA 
            GROUP BY 
                COD_FUNDO
```

Nele, você diz que quer agrupar os registros por COD_FUNDO (GROUP BY COD_FUNDO), e que no agrupamento vai querer a maior DATA_COTA (MAX(DATA_COTA)), mas não informa o que vai acontecer com o campo VALOR. Você quer que Some, o Máximo o Mínimo, ou quer agrupar pro valores ?? Acho que este pode ser a questão.

Um abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Re-formatando a expressão de SQL:

```
SELECT
  C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO ,
  ROUND(SUM(FA.COTAS * FA.VALOR_COTA),2) AS SALDO_APLIC
FROM CONTA C
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      FA.NRO_CONTA,
      FA.COD_FUNDO,
      FA.NRO_COTAS AS COTAS,
      DC.VALOR_COTA AS VALOR_COTA
    FROM FUNDOS_APLIC FA
    JOIN (
      SELECT 
        COD_FUNDO,
        MAX(DATA_COTA) AS DATA_COTA,
        VALOR_COTA
      FROM FUNDOS_COTA 
      GROUP BY COD_FUNDO
    ) DC ON FA.COD_FUNDO = DC.COD_FUNDO 
    GROUP BY FA.COD_FUNDO, FA.NRO_CONTA 
  ) FA ON C.NRO_CONTA = FA.NRO_CONTA
```

torna-se mais fácil de perceber onde estão os erros. Das queries exteriores para as interiores:

```
SELECT
  C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO ,
  ROUND(SUM(FA.COTAS * FA.VALOR_COTA),2) AS SALDO_APLIC
FROM CONTA C
(...)
```

aqui são colocadas tres atributos e uma função agregadora. Seria necessário uma secção "GROUP BY C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO" no final da expressão.

```
   (...)
   SELECT 
      FA.NRO_CONTA,
      FA.COD_FUNDO,
      FA.NRO_COTAS AS COTAS,
      DC.VALOR_COTA AS VALOR_COTA
    FROM FUNDOS_APLIC FA
    (...)
    ) DC ON FA.COD_FUNDO = DC.COD_FUNDO 
    GROUP BY FA.COD_FUNDO, FA.NRO_CONTA
    (...)
```

aqui temos um "GROUP BY FA.COD_FUNDO, FA.NRO_CONTA" mas na listagem dos campos não há nenhuma função agregadora.

Por último

```
      (...)
      SELECT 
        COD_FUNDO,
        MAX(DATA_COTA) AS DATA_COTA,
        VALOR_COTA
      FROM FUNDOS_COTA 
      GROUP BY COD_FUNDO
      (...)
```

A agregação está a ser feita só pelo campo "COD_FUNDO" mas na lista de campo surge também o campo "VALOR_COTA" que deveria ser inserido na lista de campos do "GROUP BY".